# Calculate Database size of webservice record

Tags: android, realm

I am currently working on a CRM where we sync the record of last two weeks from the web server using **Realm** for local storage.
I need to sync all the data, but there's alot of data that's around 118 MB or can be more in future.

Now my question is, how can i coordinate with server such that i can know how much space the data requires in Realm, so that i can check if the phone have that much space or not **before syncing the data**.

**Note** I have checked that if i am closing the Realm instances properly already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. Realm uses a technique called Bit Packing, so the space needed on the device will vary depending on what is getting saved. However, an upper bound is probably just the size of the data you are sending.